# jQuery Force set src attribute for iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a main page (actually a JSP) with an iframe inside it as;

```
<iframe name="abc_frame" id="abc_frame" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Now there are multiple links on the main page (rendered dynamically via JSP) which can try to set the src to some URL...

Now my question is,using jQuery (may be live()), can I override that in such a way that the "src" attribute for abc_frame would always have some particular value (e.g. "somefixedURL")

I cannot capture the link clicking, as it is completely dynamically created via some Java code and hence I am trying to override the iframe src ?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#abc_frame').attr('src', url)
```

This way you can get and set every HTML tag attribute. Note that there is also `.prop()`. See [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) about the differences. Short version: `.attr()` is used for attributes as they are written in HTML source code and `.prop()` is for all that JavaScript attached to the DOM element.

Comment: The reason this would not work is after the page has been loaded, another link would change the src to a new value...

Comment: If you pleace the code at the end of the file you code will be executed after the other scripts. If you problem is created by a specific link the user clicks you could add a second onclick event to the link. Otherwise you have to use setTimout/setInterval and repeatly check the value of src (ugly!).

Answer (score 21):

if you are using jQuery 1.6 and up, you want to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) rather than `.attr():`

```
$('#abc_frame').prop('src', url)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for an explanation of the differences.

Comment: Interesting link but please note that the answer has been updated because jQuery _reverted_ `attr()` behavior. Overall I would disagree on using `.prop()` here because `src` is an attribute not an property as the API documentation for `.prop()` you linked explains.

Answer (score 9):

While generating the links set the target to the iframes name property and you probably wont have to deal with jquery at all.

```
<a href="inventory.aspx" target="contentframe"  title="Title Inventory">
<iframe id="iframe1" name="contentframe"  ></iframe>
```

Comment: Good idea to use browser's native method when possible, but I think the user has dynamic links so therefore needs to capture the click attr.

Comment: How dynamic? When generating the page just set the href to whatever you need. Or even on dom load just set the href attribute if you have to. The point is to not have to be handling the src property of the iframe and this makes it possible.

Answer (score 8):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#abc_frame').attr('src',url);
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Setting src attribute didn't work for me.
The iframe didn't display the url.

What worked for me was:

```
window.open(url, "nameof_iframe");
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: setting with .attr() also did not work for me. This works though

Comment: This solution worked fine for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(
    "<iframe id='myframe' src='http://www.example.com/" + 
    window.location.search + "' height='100' width='100%' >"
  ) 
</script>
```

This code takes the url-parameters (?a=1&b=2) from the page containing the iframe and attaches them to the base url of the iframe. It works for my purposes.

Comment: `document.write` is equivalent to using `eval()` - it's subject to script injection! Only use with extreme caution!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set FIX iframe's src or prevent javascript/form submit to change its location. However you can put script to *onload* of the page and change action of each dynamic link.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".excel").click(function () {
    var t = $(this).closest(".tblGrid").attr("id");
    window.frames["Iframe" + t].document.location.href = pagename + "?tbl=" + t;
});
```

this is what i use, no jquery needed for this. in this particular scenario for each table i have with an excel export icon this forces the iframe attached to that table to load the same page with a variable in the Query String that the page looks for, and if found response writes out a stream with an excel mimetype and includes the data for that table.