# How to reload the src of an iframe contained jquery dialog each time the dialog is opend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-dialog

I have a dialog like this

```
<div id="dialog">
  <iframe id="myIframe" src=""></iframe>
</div>
<button id="opener1">Open Dialog</button>
<button id="opener2">Open Dialog</button>
```

My script is as follows

```
$(function () {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "fade",
    hide: "fade",
    modal: true,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    resizable: true,
    title: 'Vessels'
  });

  $("#opener1").click(function () {
    $('#myIframe').src = 'http://www.w3schools.com';
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    return false;
  });

  $("#opener2").click(function () {
    $('#myIframe').src = 'http://www.google.com';
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    return false;
  });
});
```

I want to set the url of the iframe dynamically before the dialog is displayed.
I tried the above code, but not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551912/jquery-force-set-src-attribute-for-iframe

Comment: yes.. I tried that.. That is working..
but see this..http://jsfiddle.net/krishanudey/94KUB/ when you click on a button and close the dialog and then click on other button, initially it's showing previous page. I dont that to happen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Try this

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "fade",
        hide: "fade",
        modal: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        resizable: true,
        title: 'Vessels',
        close: function( event, ui ) {
           $('#myIframe').attr('src', '');
         }
    });

    $("#opener1").click(function () {
        $('#myIframe').attr('src', 'http://www.w3schools.com');
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });

    $("#opener2").click(function () {
        $('#myIframe').attr('src', 'http://www.example.com/');
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
});
```

While closing the dialog box just simply set the `iframe` `src` as `empty`

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/94KUB/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('#myIframe')[0].src = 'http://www.w3schools.com';
```

or use `attr()` like,

```
$('#myIframe').attr('src','http://www.google.com');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sq984/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the source directly.  You have to change the iframe's src attribute like this:

```
$('#myIframe').attr('src','http://www.w3schools.com');
```

Comment: yes.. I tried that.. That is working..
but see this..http://jsfiddle.net/krishanudey/94KUB/ when you click on a button and close the dialog and then click on other button, initially it's showing previous page. I don't that to happen...