# Dynamically set src in iframe - not working

Tags: jquery, iframe

Here's my relevant HTML:

```
       <div id="activity-menu">
          <h2><a id="activity-link-reddittv" href="#" data-url="https://app.herokuapp.com/reddit-tv/reddittv.html">Watch RedditTV</a></h2>
          <h2><a id="activity-link-topics" href="#">Topics</a></h2>
       </div>

       <div id="topics" style="display:none;" >
       </div> 

       <div id="#reddit-tv-div" style="display:none;" >
          <iframe id="reddit-tv-iframe" style="height:100%;width:100%;" style="border:none;"></iframe> 
       </div>
```

And here's my JQuery:

```
  $('#activity-link-reddittv').click(function(){

                var el = $(this);

                $('#activity-menu').hide();
                $('#reddit-tv-div').show();
                $('#reddit-tv-frame').attr('src', el.data('url'));

                console.log('el = ' + el); 
                console.log('el.url = ' + el.data('url')); 
                console.log('src = ' + $('#reddit-tv-frame').attr('src')); 

              });
```

Here's my logs:

```
el = [object Object] 
el.url = https://app.herokuapp.com/reddit-tv/reddittv.html
src = undefined
```

The iframe doesn't show up, and based on the logs `src` never gets set.

This question has been answered numerous times on SO - [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551912/jquery-force-set-src-attribute-for-iframe). My code seems to follow these answers pero no funciona.

Comment: you have inconsistency between id in html and as jQuery selector. `reddit-tv-iframe` vs `reddit-tv-frame`

Comment: You have a typo, you're missing the `i` before `frame` in `$('#reddit-tv-frame')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is missing in "*#reddit-tv-**frame***". Correct the spelling.

```
$('#reddit-tv-iframe').attr('src', el.data('url'));
```